# CVRPTW with real distances and variable fleet

Tags: java, optaplanner

The optaplanner working [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxO3UFmtAPg)  uses a fixed fleet. Is there any file format (template) where besides the distance matrix it accepts a heterogeneous fleet?

The original vrp file its [here](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/vrp-dataset-generator/blob/master/data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/timewindowed/road-time/belgium-road-time-tw-n500-k20.vrp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can load the demand .vrp file and then save it witout solving after that u will get .xml file where u can edit each vehicle and load the .xml file to solve or u can modify `VehicleRoutingImporter` where .vrp file is loaded. IIRC this is the method where vehicle part is started `createVrpWebVehicleList()`